# apply selected to last option with ng-repeat in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How can I apply a `selected` attribute to the last option inserted with `ng-repeat` in AngularJS? I'm inserting the HTML as so:

```
<select class="form-control half" ng-model="selectValue">
    <option></option>
    <option data-ng-repeat="mf in SearchCtrl.manifacturers | orderBy: SearchCtrl.manifacturers">
        {{ mf }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Now I know about `data-ng-attr-selected="$last && selected || none"`, but the problem about selected is that is doesn't rely on the value of an attribute, but simply inserting the attribute itself.

So my question stands, is it possible to apply an attribute to the last element in an array.

**Also a side question:** is it possible to apply `selected` to the first - empty option before the array if no results are being returned to the array?

Sorry if the question is unclear, if it is, ask away and I'll try to simplify, thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in most cases when creating a `<select>` in angular, the easiest way to do it is using [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) like this and will create the options for you and handle adding and removing:

```
<select ng-model="yourModel" ng-options="element for element in array"></select>
```

The link to ngOptions has more ways to customize this to control what gets shown in the option and what data gets passed to the model when you select one of the options.

Now, on to your question:

The variable you pass into the ng-model is a 2 way binding, so by changing the model you it will set the `selected` attribute on the option with the value matching the model. So if you do something like this in your controller, it would set it to be the first option:

```
selectValue = SearchCtrl.manifacturers[0];
```

for the last one you could just do

```
selectValue = SearchCtrl.manifacturers[SearchCtrl.manifacturers.length - 1];
```

Also, if the array is empty, there will just be a single empty option that is selected. Now if you wanted this to be something more reusable where it will just select the first or last option based on some expression, you could make a directive for it. If this is not what you are asking, please clarify then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. sorry for the late vote-give. I see what you mean, I'll try and manage something, maybe post an answer as to what I did exactly, but your answer is more than satisfying, so, likes to you, sir!

Comment: Actually `selectValue = SearchCtrl.manifacturers[0];` is wrong, it should be `$scope.selectValue = SearchCtrl.manifacturers[0];` . But I'm guessing you figured that out

Comment: yep, yep, I know about scope variables! :) thanks again!